# Scale keeps changing in QGIS composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale

Every time I pan the map content in the QGIS composer window the scale changes. Is there a way to make it stick at specific scale?

Comment: By how much is the scale changing? What's the projection used, and the area of interest?

Comment: The scale changes slightly dropping from 1:50000 to 1:49800 when I pan using the pan content tool. I've been setting the scale under the item properties>map>scale field. Using EPSG:4326 - WGS 84. Area of interest is SW Nunavut.

Comment: Tested in my QGIS 2.2 and it changes slightly indeed +/- 100 (or more if you go a lot to north/south). Well it is not that hard to set it back to 50000 though someone could report it to http://hub.qgis.org/